# Getting 404 error if i am navigating to any URL other than homepage URL with react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I have my routes.js as

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={login}/>
      <Route path="/calculator" component={calculatorPage}/>
      <Route path="/result" component={resultPage}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

I have hoisted the application on a server , when i try to enter the URL with /calculator , i am getting 404 error. If i go with home page URL , to calculator page , it works fine. If i enter directly then i get a 404 error.

In my local everything works fine . Even if i put /calculator directly , i get the page.

Comment: What's in front of your application? nginx? apache? regardless, you need to make sure that _all_ paths serve whatever your `index.html` is

Comment: @TylerSebastian, its apache , hoisted on a windows machine . Anyways , in my local everything works , even if enter calculator in the URL directly. But not in the server .

Comment: right because locally, you're probably running `webpack` dev-server with something like `history-api-fallback` you need to configure apache to always server your `index.html`. see something like https://askubuntu.com/questions/484986/how-do-i-make-apache-serve-a-single-static-page-no-matter-what-the-entered-url-i

Comment: you have to look for `server side rendering` if you want to deploy your app  in production mode && refreshing your URLs

Comment: @Atulkumarsingh Tyler said it right. Your Apache server has no knowledge of `/calculator` or `/result`, so you need to instruct it to rewrite all requests to `index.html`, and then on the frontend, those will be matched to the proper React routes.

Answer (score 0):

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteBase /<YOUR_BASE_URL_HERE>/
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```